# must do configurations in tomcat for prod configuration?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

Anyone has some pointers/recipe for must/should do configurations for putting a war into production with Tomcat 6.0.20?
I understand that it depends on my application, I just want to leverage the communities experience :-)

My application will mainly receive webservice requests (CXF and Spring security) store them to DB (JPA/Hibernate) and then send the data received to some 50 subscribing systems via different protocols.
I will also run to slightly different versions of the same application (two war-files) under separate contexts.

Cheers!
Tomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read this, 20 tips for using tomcat in production](http://www.digitalsanctum.com/2007/08/18/20-tips-for-using-tomcat-in-production/), its worth it. Another link found [Putting Tomcat in Production](http://azeditech.com/tomcat-production.html).